# how to find the directory that contains the test with the last date?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a directory that has many files and directories, 
I want to find which one of the directories that are with name format that has the date :

p**_yyyymmdd

can I write a command that can find (through name not timestamp) that shows the directory name that has the last date (highest yyyy then highest mm then highest dd) in shell script ?

Add the file name sample here:

```
p00_20131208 p00_20131220 p00_20140107 p01_20130324
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of these directories?

Comment: p00_20131208

p00_20131220

p00_20140107

p01_20130324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a directory that has many files and directories,

Looks like you want to do that this in one directory only then you do this:

```
cd /my/directory

p1='p*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
printf "%s\n" $p1|sort -t_ -nk2|head -1
```

Comment: I used your command with the sort command that user Daniele suggested and the final command was :


ls -dtr p**_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | sort -n | tail -1

because yours alone gives me the last modified timestamp not the last that has the last date but thanks!

Comment: Actually you don't need sort here since I am using `ls -tr` which already does the sorting.

Comment: let me explain to you what is the case : lets say I have five folders here :

p00-20130203     p00-20130403         p00-20130503      p00-20140203      gwmposd_ap

        let us suppose that before I executed your command, I modified content of one of the folders p00-20130403 for example. executing your command will not give me the result I am looking for which is p00-20140203, but will give me the last modified which is p00-20130403. that`s why you need sort.

Comment: Ok got it, sort can be added for this case but find is overkill since we're dealing with single directory only.

Comment: Check updated answer with much stronger way to find latest directory with given pattern.

Comment: Ok I agree, is there a way that this command take a variable in the place of p* (instead of p* it will take a value stored in variable like p1)

Comment: Sure that can be done too, see my edited answer now.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type d -name 'p??_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' |
sort -t _ -k2nr |
head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

This script will find every directory whose name finish with 6 digits and put them in file tmp.

In the second part it extracts the date from the name (it get the last 6 characters, so it's not a problem if the folder returned by the find start with a relative path like ./ or ./subfolder/).

Finally it will find the latest date and print the folder with the corresponding name.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d | egrep "p.._[0-9]{6}" > tmp

date=$(for r in $(cat tmp)
do
    echo ${r: -6}
done | sort -nr | head -1)
cat tmp | grep $date
```

Comment: I used the Sort method that you suggested here with a command that extracts the date, it worked : final command was :
ls -dtr p00_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | sort -n | tail -1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no multiple directories with the same date:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
unset newestDir
for currDir in `ls -1f`
do
    if [[ -d "$currDir" && "$currDir" =~ ^p.*_[0-9]{8}$ ]]; then
        if [[ ! "$newestDir" ]]; then
            newestDir=$currDir
        else
            newestDate=${newestDir:(-8)}
            currDate=${currDir:(-8)}
            if (( $currDate > $newestDate )); then
                newestDir=$currDir
            fi
        fi
    fi
done

echo $newestDir
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
find . -type d -name "p*" -exec ./process {} \; | sort > file
```

after saving the following as file "process" and running "chmod +x process"

```
#!/bin/bash
p=$1
yyyymmdd=${p#*_}    # Strip everything before underscore
y=${yyyymmdd:0:4}   # Extract 4 chars for year
m=${yyyymmdd:4:2}   # Extract 2 chars for month
d=${yyyymmdd:6:2}   # Extract 2 chars for day
echo $y $m $d $p
```

Obviously you can sort the file differently and do what you like with it.